# Function to group things together?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Hey guys a friends father asked me if I knew how to do a task on excel however I don't so to help him I figured I would ask here. This is what he is trying to do.

He has an excel sheet that looks something similar to this:

```
    A          B 
1   House 1    card 1 
2   House 1    card 2
3   House 1    card 3 
4   House 1    card 4
```

There are about 500 entries similar to this. So instead of going in and manually taking each card and moving it to the first row then deleting the other House 1 entries is there a function of some sort that would group anything with the same name together and their following entries. As a visual he is looking to turn the previous example into this:

```
  A        B       C       D       E
1 House 1  card 1  card 2  card 3  card 4
```

Thank you for any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 2):

***IF*** your list is sorted on column A then this method will give you what you want.

Copy the list in column A to another column.

Then use Remove Duplicates to get a unique list:

[image]

Then in the first cell next to the first item put:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A:A)>COUNTIF($A:$A,$E1),"",INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($E1,$A:$A,0)+COLUMN(A:A)-1))
```

Then copy over as many columns as the highest number of items.  Then copy down to the bottom of the list.

[image]

Then copy and paste the values into a new sheet or on itself.

---

If you want to do it in place; I wrote this code for another site that will remain nameless.  It will do exactly what you want fairly quickly in place:

```
Sub FOOO()
Dim inArr() As Variant
Dim outArr() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cntrw As Long
Dim cntclm As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws
    Set rng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    'find the max number column that will be needed in the output
    cntclm = ws.Evaluate("MAX(COUNTIF(" & rng.Address & "," & rng.Address & "))") + 1
    'find the number of rows that will be needed in the output.
    cntrw = ws.Evaluate("SUM(1/COUNTIF(" & rng.Address & "," & rng.Address & "))")
    'put the existing data into an an array
    inArr = rng.Resize(, 2).Value
    'resize output array to the extents needed
    ReDim outArr(1 To cntrw, 1 To cntclm)
    'put the first value in the first spot in the output
    outArr(1, 1) = inArr(1, 1)
    outArr(1, 2) = inArr(1, 2)
    'these are counters to keep track of which slot the data should go.
    j = 3
    k = 1
    'loop through the existing data rows
    For i = 2 To UBound(inArr, 1)
        'test whether the data in A has changed or not.
        If inArr(i, 1) = inArr(i - 1, 1) Then
            'if not put the value in B in the next slot and iterate to the next column
            outArr(k, j) = inArr(i, 2)
            j = j + 1
        Else
            'if change start a new line in the outarr and fill the first two slots
            k = k + 1
            j = 3
            outArr(k, 1) = inArr(i, 1)
            outArr(k, 2) = inArr(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    'remove old data
    .Range("A:B").Clear
    'place new data in its place.
    .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(outArr, 1), UBound(outArr, 2)).Value = outArr
End With
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

***NOTE:*** both methods require that Column A be sorted.